# How and where do I store user preferences with the Chrome.storage API in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to store the value of a checkbox in the `popup.html` file. I have these two functions in my `popup.js` file:

```
function storeUserPrefs() {
    var isHighlighting = false;
    var highlightedCheckBoxVal = $("#highlightedCheckbox").is(":checked");
    chrome.storage.sync.set({isHighlighting: highlightedCheckBoxVal}, function() {
        console.log("saved " + isHighlighting + "as " + highlightedCheckBoxVal);
    })
}

function getUserPrefs() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['isHighlighting'], function(result) {
        console.log('Value is currently ' + result.isHighlighting);
      });
}
```

My first question is:

If I am trying to save the true/false value of the variable `isHighlighting` and then set the saved value to the `highlightedCheckBoxVal` **will these two functions do that correctly?**

My second question is:

**Where do I call these two functions?** Should I keep them in `popup.js` or should I put one in `background.js`?

My third question is:

**Would I use the Chrome.storage.onChanged function to update these values every time the checkbox is checked/unchecked?**

Any help is greatly appreciated, and please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to save the true/false

set() is fine.

get() does nothing useful so its callback needs something like

```
$("#highlightedCheckbox").prop('checked', result.isHighlighting)
```

> Where do I call these two functions

In the popup.

The background script runs in a separate hidden background page with its own empty DOM.

> use the Chrome.storage.onChanged function

No.

Register a `change` or `click` listener that calls set() to store the new value.

Do it at the beginning of the script and add getUserPrefs() call to load the data every time the popup opens:

```
$("#highlightedCheckbox").change(storeUserPrefs)
getUserPrefs();
```

Comment: This was helpful, but it is still not saving the value. The console says that `result.isHighlighting` is undefined when the popup opens. Any thoughts?

Comment: I can't help further without seeing the complete code. Maybe you didn't put the `change` listener where I suggested or there's something else wrong in your popup.js. Anyway, all of this is a matter of debugging which you can conveniently perform in devtools for the popup window.