# How to make async function return boolean value rather than a promise

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pull the boolean value of a checkbox in my `popup.html` file in my chrome extension. I have this:

```js
var highlightedCheckBoxVal = $("#highlightedCheckbox").prop("checked");

function getAsync(valueToGet) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(valueToGet, (value) => {
            resolve(value);
            console.log("resolved");
        })
    })
}


//returns object - I want it to return true or false
$(document).keyup(async function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 120) {
        getAsync("highlightedCheckBoxVal").then(val => {
            console.log(val);
        });
    }
});
```

The console returns an object, and I want it to return a boolean value. I think this is because `getAsync` is returning a promise, but **how can I make that promise a boolean value?**

I have also tried logging `val.valueOf()`.

Comment: Your code looks correct. What does the object look like? Is the boolean value you want to retrieve stored in a property of the object?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://ibb.co/RzNsCtT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) the callback receives an object that contains all requested keys (you can request an array of strings) so the solution is to extract the key as `result[key]`.

```
function getAsync(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, (data) => resolve(data[key]));
  });
}
```

Comment: Although this makes sense, the console is now returning undefined.

Comment: @GrahamBillington it means you're not saving the value correctly, for example the common pitfall is not setting the key correctly as `{[keyVariable]: value}`

Comment: Where do I set the key as you explained? @wOxxOm

Comment: Uhm? In the code that sets the value. To read the value you need to write it first.

Comment: The value is set as `$("#highlightedCheckbox").prop("checked");`. How would I set it 'correctly'

Comment: This code doesn't set anything in storage. See the documentation: you need to use chrome.storage.sync.set. BTW this topic looks like the [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641541/how-and-where-do-i-store-user-preferences-with-the-chrome-storage-api-in-a-chrom).

Comment: It is similar, yes. Same problem, different approach.

Comment: My plan is to set the value in the storage with the boolean value of the function. The problem still persists as the promise is returning undefined. Is there something I am not understanding? @wOxxOm

Comment: Like I said, you need to set the value in storage to be able to read it afterwards. Use chrome.storage.sync.set in a listener for `change` event of the checkbox element.